# How to delete an iOS app you can't find in Springboard?

Tags: ios, springboard

I have way too many apps on my iPhone, so many that I can't find any given app in the folders and pages of the Springboard Home screens any more.

If I can't find it, how do I delete it?

I don't want to use iTunes for this if there's any way at all to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, found it.

Settings / General / Usage / Manage Storage / app / Delete App.